# --debug-init changes emacs behaviour

Tags: warning

I have a warning when I start Emacs.
[image: Warning when starting Emacs]
No problem, just start it with --debug-init.
[image]
What!! No warning anymore, and it actually opens *scratch* instead of Emacs standard spash screen.

`--debug-init` removes the warning and gives me the correct behavior, but without it I get a warning and ... Well, not the desired behavior.

I am running emacs 25.1.RC1, same problem with 25.1.50. I have not tested with 24.X.X but I am about to do that now.
Emacs is homebuild on a mac osx 10.11.5 El Capitan with `--with-cocoa --with-gnutls --with-rsvg --with-imagemagick --with-ns`. Any recommendations?

Comment: Tell me if you want an .emacs.d summary

Comment: It's unlikely we're going to be able to fix this without your init.d. Your best bet is to recursively bisect it, commenting out half, to narrow down where the problem is. That said, "End of file during parsing" probably means a missing closing parenthesis or quotation mark.

Comment: What sometimes helped me to find the source of such a bug is to open your `init.el` mark the whole buffer and `M-x indent-region`. Inspect the buffer to see if something is indented strangely. If this did not help save it as another file, open `init.el` again and diff the two files to find differences.

Comment: The warning is still there.  You've probably got an open parenthesis somewhere without a closing parenthesis.

Comment: @dan Saw that now, the warning went kind of incognito on me and I jumped down the wrong rabbit hole. I feel a little (way) bit stupid...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visit your `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file and do `M-x check-parens RET`.  It should show you the unclosed open paren in that file.

As for `--debug-init`, I guess you could `M-x report-emacs-bug` indicating that it did not help debug the problem.  I think that is because of `debug-ignored-errors` which should probably be bound to `nil` during initialization.